# Solutions of the trigonometric funtion

Tags: trigonometry

How to determine the number of solutions of the following equation? $$x\tan x = 1 \\ for ~~ -2\pi \le x \le 2\pi$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: see where the $\tan$ function has discontinuities.
- Step 2: see what are the left and right limits of $x\tan x$ around these points
- Step 3: see where $x\tan x = 0$
- Step 4: Calculate $x\tan x$ at $\pm2\pi$
- Step 5: Check zeros for the derivative
- Step 6: Create a table with these values. You will immediately observe a pattern. Maybe try to sketch this function

Answer (score 0):

The function $x tan(x)$ is symmetric about $x=0$, so we need only concern ourselves with $x>=0$.

In the range $0$ ... $2\pi$ the function takes on every value from $-\infty, +\infty$ but only takes each value once.  That is, every $x$ in that range maps to a unique value of $x\,tan(x)$.

So there is only one place in that range that it can have the value $1$.

As the function is symmetric, it is easily seen there can be only two values where the equation is satisfied between $-2\pi$ and $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x\tan(x)$ is an even function so we need only to check for values in $[0,2\pi]$.

If $x$ is solution then $-x$ will be too.

$f'(x)=\tan(x)+\dfrac{x}{\cos(x)^2}=\dfrac{x+\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos(x)^2}=\dfrac{2x+\sin(2x)}{2\cos(x)^2}> 0$

*From the inequality $\forall u>0,\ \sin(u)<u$ applied to $u=2x$.*

So $f$ is strictly $\nearrow$ on each interval where it is defined.

The asymptotics verticals are these of $\tan(x)$, so where $\cos(x)=0\iff x\in\{\dfrac{\pi}2,\dfrac{3\pi}2\}$.

We can now draw a variation array:

$\begin{array}{|l|cccccccc|}\hline
x & 0 && \frac{\pi}2 && \frac{3\pi}2 && 2\pi \\ \hline
f' && + &\mid& + &\mid& + \\ \hline
f & 0 &\nearrow & +\infty\mid-\infty &\nearrow & +\infty\mid-\infty &\nearrow& 0\\ \hline
\end{array}$

Since $f$ is continuous on each of the intervals $A=[0,\frac{\pi}2[,\ B=]\frac{\pi}2,\frac{3\pi}2[,\ C=]\frac{3\pi}2,2\pi[$ we can apply the intermediate value theorem to find a value such that $f(x)=1$, the strict monotonicity of $f$ ensures this solution is unique.

$1\in f(A)$ so there is a value $\alpha\in A$ such that $f(\alpha)=1$

$1\in f(B)$ so there is a value $\beta\in B$ such that $f(\beta)=1$

$1\notin f(C)$ so there is no solution in this interval.

Finally in $[-2\pi,2\pi]$, there are $4$ solutions $\{-\beta,-\alpha,\alpha,\beta\}$.